# Google spreadsheet javascript macros remove rows with specific element bigger than a value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet of this form:

[image]

I want to write a macro to remove the rows where the first element of the row is bigger than a specific size (lets say 650).

I found [this very similar macro](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates?hl=en) which removes the duplicate rows and I changed it to this:

```
function removeBigRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    if(row[1] <650){
        newData.push(row);
      } 
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

I ran it a couple of times but it does not work. Where is my mistake and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array data is a two dimensional array. The first row first column is 
data[0][0]. This will work:

```
function removeBigRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
     if(data[i][0] <=650){
        newData.push(data[i]);
     } 
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```